# What do these Intel Memory Specifications mean?

Tags: memory, cpu

I am looking at these memory specifications for an [Intel® Core™ i7-4790K Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz).

[image: Memory specifications]

Specifically I am interested in the following which have these tool-tips. The first seems reasonably clear, but the second does not.

> **Max Memory Size**
>
> Max memory size refers to the maximum memory capacity (in GB)
>   supported by the processor.
>
> **Memory Types**
>
> Intel® processors come in four different types: a Single Channel, Dual
>   Channel, Triple Channel, and Flex Mode.

Am I correct in the following?

1. Max Memory Size is the maximum amount of RAM this CPU will work with. E.g. I could plug in 64GB RAM, but only 32GB will be used.
2. Memory Type is the supported RAM configurations, where "1333/1600" is the supported MHz of the RAM. E.g. attaching some DDR3 2400MHz won't provide any additional performance above 1600MHz.

---

I've done a bit more digging by comparing to the Intel Datasheets.

[Intel® Core™ i7-920 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI), [Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.html).

[image: Intel® Core™ i7-920 Processor specifications]

[Intel® Core™ i7-4790K Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz), [Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.html).

[image: Intel® Core™ i7-4790K Processor specifications]

The interesting thing to note here, is that for the i7-920 the technical specification refers to MHz,

> DDR3 speeds of 800/1066 MHz supported

Whilst for the i7-4790K, the specification refers to MT/s.

> Memory data transfer rates of 1333 MT/s and 1600 MT/s

So its not especially clear which units Intel are actually using.

Comment: 1. Correct. 2, Correct

Comment: Per your quote, the Memory Type is not the frequency of the RAM (1300/1600MHz) but the way the CPU addresses it via the bus to RAM. A Dual Channel architecture uses two sets of RAM slots simultaneously in parallel, whereas Tripple channel uses three. The downside to using multi-channel architechures is that the RAM in each slot on in each set must match in size and frequency. Flex-Mode is a compromise that allows you to add non-matching chips to different channels, and obtain some (or most if you believe Intel) of the performance gains from using multiple matched channels.

Comment: @Moab, @FrankThomas; do you know if its MHz or MT/s (or both?!), see my edit, cheers

Comment: The speed of memory is always a frequency.  DDR3 is DDR3 so saying either the frequency or transfer rate is saying the same thing

Comment: " If its internal clock runs at 100 MHz, then the effective rate is 200 MT/s, because there are 100 million rising edges per second and 100 million falling edges per second of a clock signal running at 100 MHz"

Comment: @Ramhound, then would 800MHz be 1600 MT/s? I don't see how the memory type value can be both MHz and MT/s given they are different units of measurement.

Comment: One is frequency one is the transfer rate, how you got from frequency to the transfer rate, is simple math.  Easier to answer a different question, what memory, are you interested in precisely ?

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm not, I stumbled across these specifications out of curiosity. Generally speaking I understand MHz and MT/s and the conversion between them. What isn't clear is if the value in the Intel Memory Specifications is in the MHz or MT/s unit. Without knowing what the original unit is, it is impossible to perform the conversion sensibly. E.g. is 1333/1600 as written by Intel MHz or MT/s? It seems likely that the unit is in MHz, but the information contained in the datasheet would seem to contradict this.

Comment: `is 1333/1600 as written by Intel MHz or MT/s` In MT/sec, else it would be sold as DDR-3 2666 or DDR-3200 by shops. And that is ludricous speed.

Answer (score 5):

Please remember that these specifications are Marketing specifications, not technical. Whichever team was charged with responsibility for product marketing, they use whatever terms they believe are right.

The relationship between the provided parameters is actually consistent. Let's take an example of i7-4790K.

1. The key parameter is "2-channel", or "Dual-channel". This means that the processor supports (has enough wires/pins) to drive/control two DIMMs in parallel. In addition, due to signal integrity challenges (and the number of slot select control pins), each channel can be restricted to two DIMM slots in each channel. The older i7-9xx chips were made to support "Triple cahnnel", and therefore used to have a bigger pin count.
2. The next most important info is the Memory Type. DDR3 is the type, "L" means that the controller can reduce supply voltage from 1.8V to lower-power 1.5V if the DIMM reports itself as such in SPD channel.
3. The max memory speed can be calculated from "Max memory bandwidth" of 25.6 GBytes/s. Since two DIMMS are operating in parallel, the memory data width is 16 Bytes. So, 25600/16 = 1600, or exactly as it says in the "Memory Types" section. Since the DDR3 is still a dual-data-rate memory, the memory bus operates at 800MHz. Apparently, the CPU can scale down the SDRAM operating frequency to 1333 MT/s, or 666MHz.
4. Max memory supported reflects the CPU package / bonding capability to have the corresponding number of address lines. Total of 32GB on a dual-channel system means 16GB per channel max, either 2DIMMs X16GB, or 4DIMMs x 4GB. The i7-920 has three channels, so the best configuration is 6DIMMs x 4GB each.
5. The ECC and "registered" RAM are different types of memory, and are not supported by i7-4790K chip

Usually an interesting question arises if a DIMM with a bigger memory is installed. The answer depends on how well and updated is the BIOS for the particular platform. Configuring the memory controller to work with a particular DIMM depends on information supplied by DIMM via SPD, and pre-compiled configuration tables that the BIOS has. There are many timing parameters that needs to be set, CAS, RAS, refresh, etc. If the BIOS does not have a proper entry for the reported DIMM size, it will likely fail/refuse to configure the memory at all.